# A word to describe "quit original group and join another group"

Tags: word-request

I want to use some kind of noun form to describe

`the request from a member that quit his original group and join a new group`.

And I tried to create the word by myself (which doesn't look so "english" but helps you understand my purpose) like so :

> group switching request
>
> group changing request

Are there any better options ? Looking forward to your suggestions!

Comment: what kind of group is it? A political party, a sports team, a social network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a formal sense, I would use:

> transfer request